# valet local domain with browser sync Laravel mix

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-mix, laravel-valet

I have load laravel project which runs fine with valet domain **something.dev**

Tried to implement browser sync with laravel-mix

```
mix.browserSync({
    proxy: 'something.dev'
});
```

After running `npm run watch` it is pointing me to `http://localhost:3000/`

Can i point to to valet domain instead of localhost:3000 ?

Here is the output of `npm run watch`

```
Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
mix.js  2.59 kB       0  [emitted]  mix
[Browsersync] Proxying: http://something.dev
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 --------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://192.168.1.131:3000
 --------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://192.168.1.131:3001
 --------------------------------------
[Browsersync] Watching files...
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had similar issues myself getting browserSync working with Valet, but the options I use are:

```
mix.browserSync({
    proxy: 'something.test',
    host: 'something.test',
    open: 'external'
});
```

**host** overrides any detection of hostname in browserSync

**open** tells it which URL to open (local by default)

Comment: Worked for me too!

Comment: it is taking me to something.test:3000, how can I avoid this?

Comment: @AliGajani Is it still loading the page in the browser? Browsersync requires the port in order to synchronise on updates.  If it's a different port that you need, then you just need to add the "port" option and set it to whichever port you want. Browsersync will increment the port if you run another instance simultaneously.  If you wish to remove the port altogether, unfortunately that will just give you the project without Browsersync connected.

Comment: No, is not that we need another port. It's just that with Valet you don't specify the port. When we use Valet we only set the name of the folder and the .test extension and that's it. Fore example, in my case I'm using https://test1.test, but your code is taking me now to https://test1.test:3000, which doesn't works of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using valet and ran into an issue where the browsersync doesn't start, here's the answer. I was banging my head on the wall over this but found a clue in their [Upgrade to Mix 6](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/upgrade) docs. After reading this, here's my setup:

```
// package.json
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "build": "mix --production",
        "dev": "mix watch" // <--- add this script, you need to run mix watch
    },
    ...
}
```

Then in my webpack.mix.js

```js
// webpack.mix.js

const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const homedir = require('os').homedir();

const host = 'your-local-domain.test';

// ... other mix stuff

mix.browserSync({
    hot: true,
    ui: false,
    proxy: `https://${host}`,
    host,
    port: 8080,
    open: 'external',
    notify: true,
    files: ['**/*.php', 'dist/**/*.(js,css)'],
    
    // if you're using valet with https, point to cert & key
    https: {
        key: `${homedir}/.config/valet/Certificates/${host}.key`,
        cert: `${homedir}/.config/valet/Certificates/${host}.crt`,
    },
});
```

Let me know if I'm missing anything!